# How to import glew library to QT

Tags: qt, import, glew

I want to ask if anybody could help with importing glew library to QT 4.7 on windows 7.
I visited glew website and downloaded glew library, copied glew32.dll to my system32 folder. But I dont know what to do next. Qt does not recognize glew wehen i try to include it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same for every library that's compiled to a shared  or static library.

1) Put the header somewhere in your program's include path.

2) Use the symbols defined in the header.

3) Link to the library. In your case, just put the dll alongside your compiled executable.

Comment: so i added 
LIBS += C:/Windows/System32/glew32.lib
to my .pro file but qt still does not recognize glew when including

Comment: "qt still does not recognize glew when including"  What do mean -  unresolved inclusions, method not declared compiler errors?

Comment: Does glew32.lib exist? I thought you said you were using dll's. Also, what have you done with the header?

Comment: @JanHusenica This was step 3, so you have to do step 1 to make the header files *includable* from within your project! `lib != headers`

Comment: Sorry I messed up .dll and .lib. I read through some forums and tryed pretty much evrything but I couldnt get it to work. I ported/rewrieted the project to visual Studio and everything work fine now. Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: @JanHusenica Glad you got your problem resolved, but this _will_ come back and bite you again. You ought to learn the basics of include files, linking to static libraries, and linking to dynamic libraries.